# How to define a macro to interpret a unicode character with Mathjax

Tags: macros, mathjax

I have the following markup in my page:

```html
<p>$$\textbf{P} = \left⌊ \frac{\left( \left⌊ \frac{\textbf{A}}{100}\right⌋  \times 8 + 13 \right)}{25}\right⌋  - 5$$</p>
```

When MathJax tries to render it, I have the following error:

```
Missing or unrecognized delimiter for \left
```

I figured that the left floor (`⌊`) and right floor (`⌋`) unicode characters are what is not recognized in my expression because when I replace them with `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`, it's working properly.

My MathJax configuration is the following:

```js
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
    displayMath: [['$$', '$$']]
  }
};
```

I've tried to add macros to interpret the unicode characters with the following configuration with no luck:

```js
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
    displayMath: [['$$', '$$']],
    macros: {
      "⌊": '{\\lfloor}',
      "⌋": '{\\rfloor}'
    }
  }
};
```

Knowing that I can't change the markup because I not the one maintaining it and I have no way of changing it, is there a configuration that will allows me to make it work.

Comment: Are you using MathJax v2 or v3? (Delimiters are special macros; your definition should make \⌊ work but that's not what you seem to be after.)

Comment: I am currently using v3.0.5

Comment: Docs are still sparse for v3. You might want to ask on the mathjax-user google group how to extend the delimiterMap via a configuration (cf. https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/blob/77bb06d267b2fe5949bf11c3b87f2a10251fc469/ts/input/tex/base/BaseMappings.ts#L344 )

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thank you! I'll look into that.